# Accessing 64-bit registry from Haskell

Tags: winapi, haskell, registry

I have a Windows program in Haskell (hence 32-bit).  I want to access the 64-bit view of the registry.  The Windows API says to use `RegOpenKeyEx` and to OR in `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` (`0x200`).  (I am using the [standard Haskell bindings](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/Win32-2.3.0.2/System-Win32-Registry.html) to the Windows API that come with the Haskell Platform.)

In my program this ends up being:

```
  import qualified System.Win32.Registry as W32
  import qualified System.Win32.Types    as W32
  ...
      let kEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x200 -- has no binding in the library currently
      let regSam = kEY_WOW64_64KEY .|. ... other flags
      bracket (W32.regOpenKeyEx rootCode kname regSam) W32.regCloseKey $ \k -> ...
```

However, I get the exception `RegOpenKeyEx: invalid argument (The system cannot find the file specified.)`

Inspecting the call in Process Monitor shows the following output:
[image]

The API call somehow ended up dropping the flag and going into the `Wow6432Node` subtree. Also illustrated, despite the event alluding `RegOpenKey` I think it's really calling into `RegOpenKeyEx` as shown in the event's stack (and the binding's error message).

*Any suggestions?*

Thanks!

Comment: Since ghc 7.6.1 it's also been possible to use Haskell in 64 bit mode on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [alternate registry view flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx) are:

```
KEY_WOW64_64KEY 0x0100  
KEY_WOW64_32KEY 0x0200
```

But you wrote:

```
let kEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x200
```

So you are actually asking for the 32 bit view. You need to write:

```
let kEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x100
```

Comment: Spot on! This was exactly the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Impressed at the attention to detail in this answer.  Really helpful cocoding